# Возможно регулировать размер кэша у карт Google в своем приложении?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, java

Доброго времени суток!
Задался вопросом, а можно ли регулировать размер кэша карт, когда они используются в приложении? Допустим пользователю не очень удобно, когда карты каждый раз загружаются.
А так же возможно ли использовать карты Google оффлайн?

Comment: Попробуем его поднять :)
Вопрос то интересен, пока поиски ничего не дали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. за год поисков так ничего и не нашлось.